# Prove the Krull dimension of coordinate ring of $y^2=x^3$ is $1$.

Tags: krull-dimension

$K$ is an algebraically closed field.

The coordinate ring is isomorphic to $K[t^2,t^3]$, whose Krull dimension is of at most $2$(by an hint in the exercise without proof), but how to show it’s exactly $1$ ?

Comment: Do you know the Going Up theorem (and related friends)? $K[X]$ is an integral extension of $K[X^{2}, X^{3}]$ and so must have the same Krull dimension. But $K[X]$ is a PID which is not a field, and so has Krull dimension $1$. (We do not need to use that $K$ is algebraically closed.)

Comment: If you want an argument which avoids using the full strength of Going Up (but uses the same main engine), my answer here is pretty explicit: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3084021/73817